# Managing multiple shops in one website through magento

Tags: magento

I am creating a portal where I will be having All shops\stores with their products for online buying. User can search products which will then show multiple shops offering that particular product. I need to ask, is this supported in Magento?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which particular problems are you facing that are blocking your progress?

Comment: I want to implement my portal on magento but confused whether this is supported by magento or not.

Answer (score 0):

Magento supports multiple stores with multiple languages for each store. Products and categories cand be added across stores but not mandatory on all stores. Magento can be configured (ex: themes, product default display type, etc) for each store / store view.

I think you will find [this post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work/) useful.